# LDAP Filter Encoder Replacement

Tags: c#, filter, ldap, encode

I have used Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.LdapFilterEncode(val) in the past. Now moving to .NET 4.5 I cannot find an equivalent to it.  Trying to clear a finding for LDAP Injection. Any input is appreciated.

Example:

```
string sAMAccountName = Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.LdapFilterEncode(value);
ds.Filter = "(sAMAccountName=" + sAMAccountName + ")";
```

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the answer to this and came across your question.  I found it here, it has been moved to a Nuget package here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/AntiXSS/ and taken out of the core framework.

According to this blog post: https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wpl the project will continue to be updated with security updates, however the last time it was updated on Nuget was 2014.

I installed the package, the namespace you need is still:

```
Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.LdapFilterEncode(value);
```